# Create shared user account in ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions

I am trying to come up with a best approach for creating a user called appuser in Ubuntu. The reason to create this user is:  
  
1. This user will be used to install and start applications like Tomcat, MySQL etc.  
2. Other users will login to system using their account. Then using su appuser, they should be able to login to this user and manage tomcat, mysql etc.

What is the best practice to create this user?

Comment: You should try to find out the solution at [server fault](http://serverfault.com/) on this topic

Answer (score 0):

```
1)Give 755 permission to mysql and tomcat folder so any one can read and execute application but dont write or modify the data.
2)also provide grant permission to mysql DB for users.

OR

those having full permission to application of tomact or mysql other user(new users) also part of that group.

OR

you can use ACL (access control list) for the same.
```